# How do I derive C expression "4 - 2 - 1"?

Tags: c, grammar, c99

I am beginning a course on compilation theory, and I can't seem to figure from the free C99 document how to derive this expression.

My two main questions are :

1) How many rules are followed? As many as possible?

For example '4' could stop at digit, or at integer-constant, or at constant. I suppose it is parsed as a constant, but I don't seem to find an answer to this question in the document.

2) How to derive 4 - 2 - 1 from the rules:

```
additive-expression:
    multiplicative-expression
    additive-expression + multiplicative-expression
    additive-expression – multiplicative-expression
```

Because of other rules I don't include for brevity's sake, constants are multiplicative-expressions.

So is the derivation

(4 - (2 - 1)), or ((4 - 2) - 1)? I know it is the latter because of the result of the substraction when executing it, but where is this notion described in the C99 document? How even is this notion named? Is it what is intended by left or right grammars?

For reference, I used [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2), it can't be (4 - (2 - 1)), for this to be the case following the rule

```
additive-expression: additive-expression - multiplicative-expression
```

then `2 - 1` would have to be a multiplicative expression, an attempt to parse that way (if the grammar is unambiguous) will fail. This is why you can force that interpretation with parenthesis (like `4 - (2 - 1)`, as `(2 - 1)` is a multiplicative expression since `( expression )` is a primary expression.

The concept I think is left [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity). You can see an instance of right associativity in the grammar for instance in 6.5.16

```
assignment-expression: unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
```

For 1), ultimately the entire file is parsed as a `translation-unit` after the preprocessor gets to it, see 5.1.1.1. If you are just parsing `4` you can't stop until it fits into the syntax somewhere. You don't start with individual characters, rather you end up with them.

Comment: Thank you, answers all my questions.